# Break bytes object into n equally sized blocks based on index

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, byte

I'm working on writing a script to break a repeating-key XOR (Vigenère) cipher.

This involves determining some number (0 < n < maybe 50) then splitting up a bytes object into n smaller blocks, where the first block contains (from the original object) indexes n, 2n, 3n, next one contains n+1, 2n+1, 3n+1... then n+y, 2n+y, 3n+y where y < n.

If n = 3, bytes [0, 2, 5, 8 etc] should be in one block, bytes [1,3,6,9] in the next block, and bytes [2,4,7,10] in the final block.

I could implement this easily with strings, but I don't know how to make it work with bytes objects. I searched and found and adapted this code:

```
blocks = [ciphertext[i:i+most_likely_keylength] for i in range(0, len(ciphertext)+1, most_likely_keylength)]

transposedBlocks = list(zip_longest(*blocks, fillvalue=0))

##ciphertext is a bytes object resulting from the following line:
##ciphertext = base64.b64decode(open('Q6.txt', 'r').read())
```

This however returns a list of tuples filled with integers, and I don't know how to 'join' those integers again so they'll be long binary objects like before. (So that I can run something nice like Crypto.Util.strxor_c on each tuple.

Any help with this 'string manipulation' for bytes objects?

Note: I'm working on the [Break repeating-key XOR](http://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/6/) challenge at cryptopals.com – I have looked at other people's solutions on Github, but they mostly use specialised crypto modules and I want to see the guts of what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, a `bytes` object *is* a sequence of integers:

```
>>> tuple(b'ciphertext')
(99, 105, 112, 104, 101, 114, 116, 101, 120, 116)
```

... so its constructor will happily accept one:

```
>>> bytes((99, 105, 112, 104, 101, 114, 116, 101, 120, 116))
b'ciphertext'
```

Knowing that, you can change your second line to this:

```
transposed = [bytes(t) for t in zip_longest(*blocks, fillvalue=0))]
```

... and you'll get `bytes` objects back:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

ciphertext = b'ciphertext'
keylength = 3

blocks = [ciphertext[i:i+keylength] for i in range(0, len(ciphertext)+1, keylength)]
# [b'cip', b'her', b'tex', b't']

transposed = [bytes(t) for t in zip_longest(*blocks, fillvalue=0)]
# [b'chtt', b'iee\x00', b'prx\x00']
```

However, there's an error in your code – because you're using `len(ciphertext)+1` rather than just `len(ciphertext)` in your call to `range()`, you get a final empty bytestring in `blocks` if the ciphertext is an exact multiple of `keylength`:

```
ciphertext = b'SplitsEvenly'

blocks = [ciphertext[i:i+keylength] for i in range(0, len(ciphertext)+1, keylength)]
# [b'Spl', b'its', b'Eve', b'nly', b'']
```

... which results in extra null bytes at the end of all the elements in `transposed`:

```
transposed = [bytes(t) for t in zip_longest(*blocks, fillvalue=0)]
# [b'SiEn\x00', b'ptvl\x00', b'lsey\x00']
```

If you drop the `+1`, it works correctly in both cases:

```
ciphertext = b'ciphertext'

blocks = [ciphertext[i:i+keylength] for i in range(0, len(ciphertext), keylength)]
# [b'cip', b'her', b'tex', b't']

transposed = [bytes(t) for t in zip_longest(*blocks, fillvalue=0)]
# [b'chtt', b'iee\x00', b'prx\x00']
```

```
ciphertext = b'SplitsEvenly'

blocks = [ciphertext[i:i+keylength] for i in range(0, len(ciphertext), keylength)]
# [b'Spl', b'its', b'Eve', b'nly']

transposed = [bytes(t) for t in zip_longest(*blocks, fillvalue=0)]
# [b'SiEn', b'ptvl', b'lsey']
```